# Why did GoogleAuth.then() stop calling callbacks?

Tags: google-signin, google-identity-toolkit

My application relies on Google Sign-In. Suddenly, today, the `GoogleAuth.then()` method has stopped calling its callbacks. This code does nothing (printing neither result):

```
gapi.auth2.init({
    client_id: 'MYID.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    scope: 'profile email'
}).then(function() {
    console.log("success called");
}, function() {
    console.log("failure called")
});
```

This code does nothing even though using other methods to interrogate signin (such as creating listeners on isSignedIn and currentUser) work correctly.

Our code hasn't changed, but this breakage appears to be slowly rolling across our customer base in what feels vaguely like Google doing some sort of rolling deployment. At the moment this problem is a couple hours old. It has stopped working on my laptop but still works on my phone. A number of our customers around the world are experiencing different results.

Is this a Google bug? How do I report it to someone?

Comment: We see this too. Quite sure it's a google issues. Do you have any update?

Comment: Are you still experiencing this problem? This should be fixed now.

Comment: This morning it seems to be working again. Is there a better/faster way than stackoverflow of reporting production emergencies like this? Google Cloud Platform Support (which we pay for) brushed us off with "not our department".

Answer (score 3):

I was today having   similar problem as I had needed a quick hack for

`<div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn">`

not working, I call it now it this way.:

```
   <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=sss"
async defer></script>

function sss() {
    auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
    auth2.isSignedIn.listen(
        function(isSigned){
            if (isSigned) onSignIn(window._auth2.currentUser.get());
            else signOut();
       })
    }
```

It works.